item level permission question - Power Apps
Just wanted to confirm how item level permissions work with power apps.
I have a power automate that breaks inheritance and assign permission on the fly when a new item is created or modified.
But it seems when i view the list in power apps it doesn't hide and show the items based on the assgned permissions.
Does powerapps use the security trimming of a sharePoint list by default
Thanks in Advvance

Power Apps use connections to interact with data - in your case, get SharePoint items. Upon opening app for first time, users are prompted to grant permissions (Allow / Don't allow) app to use their (user) context to access data in SharePoint.
One exception - there is an option for global admins to allow app to use user context to access SharePoint. Read more about Set-AdminPowerAppApisToBypassConsent.
Regarding unauthorized access - not possible. I could not replicate the situation as you described - created new Canvas app, added connection with one user that saw 3 items in list. Opened app with second user, granted access (Allow) and saw 3 items. Broke role inheritance for one item that stripped access to second user. Opened app again and second user saw only two item (as intended) while first saw all three.
Are you calling Power Automate flow to get items in that Power App? If so, your flow is using different connection in flow than app. Also that connection does not ask users to grant permissions - flow is executed with context of user that is stated that connection.

Thanks Kristaps. But I'm a bit confused here.I'm not calling power automate to get item in Power apps.
I have a standard SharePoint list and when users create or modified items there is a power automate that does the item permissions.
Now i have a canvas apps that is connected to the same list.My questionis will power apps display the items based on the item permissions. For example if i view that list in SharePoint the item permissions take effect.
Hopethis makes sense

Understood. In your case user's should see items based on their individual permissions in SharePoint. As I understand, on your side it not working properly. Maybe you can share longer and detailed step-by-step description? Kind a going into MS support realm, but can you repeat it on different form, different users, different list? :)

Item-level permissions in Power Apps allow you to control which users can view, edit, or delete individual items within a data source, like a SharePoint list or a Dataverse table. This level of access control is important in scenarios where you want to enforce data security on a per-record basis rather than at a broad data source level.
